# Wordpress widget with acf

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a widget in functions.php, all the rules, advanced custom fields creates its own fields in it, I enter content, I save, in frontend the content is displayed, but when I open the widget again to edit the content, I have blank user fields there.  What's wrong with the code? Maybe in the field update i have error?

```
if(!class_exists('CtaWidget')) {

  class CtaWidget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
    * Sets up the widgets name etc
    */
    public function __construct() {
      $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'cta_widget',
        'description' => 'CTA Widget built with ACF Pro',
      );
      parent::__construct( 'cta_widget', 'CTA Widget', $widget_ops );
    }

    /**
    * Outputs the content of the widget
    *
    * @param array $args
    * @param array $instance
    */
    public function widget( $edit_content ) {
        ?>
    }
     <div class="spoiler-container">
<div class="up-spoiler"></div>
<div class="spoiler-parent">
<div class="advant-section title-spoiler">
<?php if( get_field('spoiler_title') ): ?>
<h2><?php the_field('spoiler_title'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-overlay"></div>
<div class="spoiler-children">
 <?php if( have_rows('spoiler') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('spoiler') ): the_row(); 
     $edit_content = get_sub_field('edit_content');
     ?>
<?php echo $edit_content; ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<div class="spoiler-btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
</div> <?php
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the options form on admin
     *
     * @param array $instance The widget options
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    /**
     * Processing widget options on save
     *
     * @param array $new_instance The new options
     * @param array $old_instance The previous options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function update( $edit_content ) {
        return $edit_content;
    }

  }

}

/**
 * Register our CTA Widget
 */
function register_cta_widget()
{
  register_widget( 'CtaWidget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_cta_widget' );
```

Comment: Why are you using ACF for widget fields and not WordPress 'options'? I think I'm right in thinking that ACF fields are stored as post meta and, as you're using them in a widget, the widgets don't have post_id or post_meta...

Comment: because i used page builder, i have output content with widgets